# Error while loading raster files using GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools

I tried loading shape files using GeoTools.It is working fine.
But when i am trying to load the raster maps, i am getting some warning like
***Can't load a service for category "GridFormatFactorySpi"***
Can any one throw some light on my issue?

Comment: @Mods, This question should not be put on hold as this problem is common with GeoTools. GeoTools uses the Java SPI mechanism to create extension points. This mechanism is strange, at first, to a novice GeoTools user.

Answer (score 2):

The `GridFormatFactorySpi` interface is implemented by various formats; some examples are ArcGrid, GeoTIFF and GrassRaster.

It sounds like you need to include additional dependencies to be able to read your raster map. The three examples I cited above are GeoTools Plugins; there are others.

Without more information, such as, the type of raster you are trying to read, and the build tool (Maven, Ivy, Ant..) you are using to manage dependencies; there is little more that I can say to help you.

Comment: I am using raster file of type tif. Thank you for your reponse.

Comment: It sound like you need to include the GeoTIFF plugin. Does this help you?

Comment: I tried using it(i.e., GeoTIFF plugin).But of no use. :(

Comment: Try using the Image plugin. This plugin handles raster images that support world files containing information about the image. Supports gif+gfw, jpg/jpeg+jgw, tif/tiff+tfw and png+pgw.